# jQuery affect all the same ID divs?

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="red">this should have a red box </div>
    <div class="other">blah blah </div>
 <div id="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div id="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div id="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div id="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div id="red">this should have a red box </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.quote { border: solid red; }
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#red').addClass('quote');
});
```

It only highlights the first red div, but not the rest. I want to apply the .quote css to all the divs that are named red.

**Don't give me a css answer**

[js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5ut9z/145/)

Comment: use classes, ID's must be unique by definition

Comment: You cannot have duplicate `id` attributes. If you need to select a group of elements, use a class.

Comment: id always unique so change it as class="red"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**id** must be unique. your ids are not unique. Use `Class` attribute instead to select all of them. Give each div a class name.

```
<div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
    <div class="other">blah blah </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/5ut9z/146/)

Comment: for clarification `class` is an html attribute, it is not necessarily related to CSS  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `class` instead of `id`

Try This

```
<div class="red">this should have a red box </div>

<div class="other">blah blah </div>

 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>
 <div class="red">this should have a red box </div>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('.red').addClass('quote');
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ut9z/145/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't/should not have multiple id attributes with the same value on the same page.

i.e.

```
   <div id="red">Something</div>
   <div id="red">Something else</div>
```

is wrong

If you have multiples with the same value, it should be a class.

```
   <div class="red">Something</div>
   <div class="red">Something else</div>
```

Then your jquery code updates to:

```
$('.red').addClass('quote');
```

Comment: humm, interesting, I didn't know this, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

because it is wrong to use id with the same name in multiple html elements, for javascript the id is unique so js search only for one element and the first that match, it will applys the rule, change `id="red"` with `class="red"` and in js `$('.red').addClass('quote');`

Answer (score 1):

Id's are always unique, not only in JavaScript.

The nature of an id is to identify a entity what ever that may be.

A class it's what you need here. It's really very logical. If you would take books as an example then you can say that novel is a class of books and the id of a particular book is its ISBN number.

No matter if you're referring to a DOM, as in this case, or to programming or databases the logic is the same.